# How FireStore document reads in sub collections calculated

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a root collection of products that contains 10 documents.
Each document has a subcollection of 100 documents and no other fields.

Now if I read the documents of the products collection by

```
db.collection("products").get();
```

how many reads will be charged, Since I'm getting documents of products collection having 10 documents I will be charged for 10 reads? or each document has a subcollection of 100 documents, so I will be charged for 10*100 =1000 document reads?

Comment: Here I'm using `db.collection("products").get();` for getting the list of documents I have in the products collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Firebase Firestore you will be charged only for data you receive.
When reading a collection you won't get the subcollections with it.
That means if you have 10 produst with 100 items in theire subcollections. You will be charged only for those 10 products you get because you won't get the subcollections with that request.